# Jenkins pipeline Lockable Resources plugin:how to lock a specific resource based on defined labels

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have the following resources defined with specific labels.

```
Resource:Windows1
Labels:win10,64bit,firefox
Resource:Windows2
Labels:win10,32bit,chrome
Resource:Linux1
Labels:opensuse15.1,32bit,chrome
Resource:Linux2
Labels:opensuse15.1,64bit,chrome
Resource:Linux3
Labels:centos7,64bit,firefox
```

And have created the following pipeline inside a Jenkins project:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager as manager
    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                agent none
                steps {
                    script {      
                      def myResources = manager.get().getResources()
                      def String myLabels = manager.get().getAllLabels()
                      def notLocked = myResources.find{rName-> 
                         manager.get().fromName(rName).with{ r-> !r.isLocked() && !r.isQueued() && myLabels.contains("opensuse15.1") && myLabels.contains("chrome") && myLabels.contains("64bit")}
                                   }  
                      if(notLocked){
                         lock(notLocked){         
                                    }
                               }
                    
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
```

When trying to select a resource based on specific labels i am getting this error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.fromName() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResource) values: [Windows1]
Possible solutions: fromName(java.lang.String)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
...
```

has anyone encountered a similar situation and could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that works for me is:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent none
            steps {
                script {
                    def OS = "win10" 
                    def bit = "64bit"
                    def browser = ""
                    def manager = org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager
                    def myResources = manager.get().resources
                    def myLabels = manager.get().allLabels
                    def checkLocked = myResources.find { r -> 
                            !r.isLocked() && !r.isQueued() && r.labels.contains(OS) && r.labels.contains(bit) && r.labels.contains(browser)}
                    if(checkLocked){
                        def myResource = checkLocked.toString()
                        lock(myResource){
                        println "Resource was succesfully locked"   
                        sleep 30
                                 }
                            } else {
                            println "Sorry!!! No resource is available in this moment"    
                            }

                }
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your code assumes the wrong type for `rName`: its not a String, it's a `LockableResource`.
Therefore the whole `manager.get().fromName(rName).with{` is not needed. Try:

```
def notLocked = myResources.find { r -> 
     !r.isLocked() && !r.isQueued() 
         && myLabels.contains("opensuse15.1") 
         && myLabels.contains("chrome") 
         && myLabels.contains("64bit")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Patrice for your answer...not the final solution but help me a lot.

Comment: You post the code that worked for you as an answer, it will help others

Answer (score 0):

for pickup the qualified free resource randomly can be also handle as below:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.*

LockableResourcesManager manager = org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.get()

List criteria = [ '64bit', 'firefox' ]
List all = manager.resources.findAll { r ->
    !r.locked &&
    !r.reserved &&
    criteria.every{ c -> r.labels.split(',').collect{ it.toLowerCase() }.contains(c.toLowerCase()) }
  }
Collections.shuffle(all)
println (all?.first() ?: '')
```

btw, you can try add/remove test labels by:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.*

LockableResourcesManager manager = org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.get()

// add
manager.createResourceWithLabel('marslo-test-1', 'windows,64bit,firefox')
manager.createResourceWithLabel('marslo-test-2', 'CentOS,32bit,chrome')
manager.createResourceWithLabel('marslo-test-3', 'RHEL,64bit,firefox')

// remove
(1..3).each {
  manager.resources.remove( manager.fromName("marslo-test-${it}") )
}
```